# Java 1.8.0_60 and Tomcat 7.5.4: The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, tomcat7

First of all, I'm migrating an existing "working" Java application to a newer version of Java.  We have it working with Red Hat (REHL 6) with Java 1.8.0_60 and Tomcat 6.  NOW, we are trying to move it to Tomcat 7 (the error came from Tomcat 7.5.4).

It appears that Tomcat is getting an error creating the JAVA and CLASS file in the work directory.
[/usr/share/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/CortWebApps-NACustomer/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/nacTemplate_jsp.java

Here is the file:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
    <% String content = request.getParameter("content"); %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN">
<html xml:lang="en">
    <jsp:include flush="true" page="./includes/nacHead.jsp"/>
    <body>
        <a name=top></a>
        <table id=twoColMain height=100% width=990 border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 align=center>

            <jsp:include flush="true" page="./includes/nacHeader.jsp"/>

            <tr>
                <jsp:include flush="true" page="./includes/nacSideNav.jsp"/>
                <jsp:include flush="true" page="<%=content %>"/>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=3 class=footerBar><a href=#top>Back to Top</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=3 align=left class=footerCopy>Copyright &copy; 2007 CORT&reg;  All images and copy. All rights reserved.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Have you set a valid JAVA_HOME environment variable for tomcat to lookup the right java version? Or have you used the installer without pointing tomcat to a proper java version?

Best regards

Alex